# Anynchronously update a web page using Flask

Tags: javascript, python, flask, asynchronous

I want to write a Flask+JavaScript based program that has two files `app.py` and `index.html` where we will run a lengthy task that takes one minue to finish and when the task finishes it will automatically update the `index.html` page asynchronously.

So I wrote:

**app.py**

```
from flask import Flask, render_template
from threading import Thread
import time

app = Flask(__name__)

task_complete = False


def run_lengthy_task():
    # Perform the lengthy task here
    time.sleep(60)  # simulate a task that takes 1 minute to complete
    global task_complete
    task_complete = True


def fetch_data():
    # Fetch the updated data here and return it
    return "Updated data"


@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

**index.html**

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script>
      function startTask() {
        // Start the lengthy task in a separate thread
        const thread = new Thread(runLengthyTask);
        thread.start();
      }

      function updatePage() {
        // Check the status of the task
        if (taskComplete) {
          // The task has completed, so fetch the updated data and update the page
          document.getElementById("data").innerHTML = "Updated data";
        } else {
          // The task is still running, so set a timer to check again in a few seconds
          setTimeout(updatePage, 1000);
        }
      }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <button onclick="startTask()">Start Task</button>
    <div id="data">
      <!-- The data will be displayed here once the task finishes -->
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Unfortunately, this doesn't do what I want.

How can I fix the source code?

Comment: Python code isn't magically available in Javascript by using the camelCased names. Your Javascript needs to make an *AJAX request* to the server to start the task, and then make more regular AJAX requests to check if it's been completed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few ways to do this. To get the sort of interaction that you are looking for without a lot of hassle, you may want to look at websockets.

Flask can be extended to support these with the flask_socketio package. Here is the server-side code to expose a function that just waits a specified number of seconds and then returns some data.

**app.py**

```
from flask import Flask, render_template
from flask_socketio import SocketIO, emit, disconnect

from time import sleep

async_mode = None

app = Flask(__name__)

socket_ = SocketIO(app, async_mode=async_mode)

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html',
                           sync_mode=socket_.async_mode)

@socket_.on('do_task', namespace='/test')
def run_lengthy_task(data):
    try:
        duration = int(data['duration'])
        sleep(duration)
        emit('task_done', {'data': 'long task of {} seconds complete'.format(duration)})
        disconnect()
    except Exception as ex:
        print(ex)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    socket_.run(app, host='0.0.0.0', port=80, debug=True)
```

You will see that we are listening for a call to an event of `do_task` and we send an event of `task_done` when we are finished waiting. We pass messages in both events, the one we receive will contain a duration to wait and then we include a message in the notification that the task is done.

The client-side code for working with this is:

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Long task</title>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.3.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.socket.io/4.5.4/socket.io.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
        $(document).ready(function() {

            namespace = '/test';
            var socket = io(namespace);

            socket.on('connect', function() {
                $('#messages').append('<br/>' + $('<div/>').text('Requesting task to run').html());
                socket.emit('do_task', {duration: '60'});
            });

            socket.on('task_done', function(msg, cb) {
                $('#messages').append('<br/>' + $('<div/>').text(msg.data).html());
                if (cb)
                    cb();
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <h3>Messages</h3>
    <div id="messages" ></div>
</body>
</html>
```

We use SocketIO to make a connection to the server. Once it connects, we send an event of `do_task` with our time to wait. When the server sends the event `task_done` back, we display the message from it.

Comment: You used two end points. Can u do it with only one end-point?

Comment: In the Flask app? You need one endpoint explicitly defined with a route for delivering the HTML+JS to the browser, and one endpoint is made implicitly for the SocketIO communication. We then can define multiple events to be listened to with the socket_.on decorator. While you could push all the function calls through this one event, it would be more normal to separate them out to different decorated functions for each thing you want the front-end to ask the back-end for.